# Distribution of $\sin(X) *\cos(Y)$ where $X,Y$ are iid r.v., uniformly distributed on $[0, 2 \pi]$

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the probability density of 
$R = \sin(X) * \cos(Y)$ where
$X,Y$ are independent random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0, 2 \pi]$?

I am stuck with complicated integrals, not sure if there is a closed expression for the density. Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

$\sin X$ and $\cos Y$ are identically distributed, with $\Pr(\sin X\le x)=\Pr(X\le\sin^{-1}(x))$ so the density of $\sin X$ is $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Thus the product distribution is, for $-1\le z\le 1$,
$$
f(z)=\int_{-1}^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(z/x)^2}}\frac1{|x|}\,1_{[-x,x]}(z)\,dx
$$
$$=\left(\int_{-1}^{-|z|}+\int_{|z|}^1\right) \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2-z^2}}\frac1{|x|}\,dx
$$
$$=\left(\int_{-1}^{-|z|}+\int_{|z|}^1\right) \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-z^2}}\,dx
$$
$$=2\int_{|z|}^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-z^2}}\,dx
$$
$$
=2 K(1-z^2)
$$
where $K(m)$ is the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) with parameter $m=k^2$ (source: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_z%5E1%20%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2-z%5E2%7D%7D%5C%2Cdx) for the last part).